# PyCharm Type error Message

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a newbie trying out ML/DBN in Python (3.4) under PyCharm (Comm.Ed 4.5).
The following definition

```
def make_thetas(xmin,xmax,n):
    xs = np.linespace(xmin,xmax,n)
    widths = (xs[1:] - xs[:-1])/2.0
    thetas = xs[:-1] + widths
    return thetas
```

throws the error
*"Class 'tuple' does not define '**sub**', so the '-' operator cannot be used on its instance"*
on the - operator on the third line (widths = ....)
Any ideas on how to get this code running under PyCharm - it works alright in the interactive Python window.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

To All,
After G'g a lot I have found a workaround that seems to work within PyCharm. I say workaround because (even as a Python newbie) I expected that Python does not need *explicit* typecasting, especially not when using datatypes imported from a lib such as Numpy.

```
    def make_thetas(xmin,xmax,n):
    xs = np.array(np.linspace(xmin,xmax,n))
    widths = (xs[1:] - xs[:-1])/2.0
    thetas = xs[:-1]+ widths
    return thetas
```

Using docstrings for type-hinting such as below did not work

```
def make_thetas(xmin,xmax,n):
    """
    @type xs: np.multiarray.ndarray
    """
    xs = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,n)
    widths = (xs[1:] - xs[:-1])/2.0  # Error Msg 1
    thetas = xs[:-1]+ widths         # Error Msg 2  Followup of Error 1
    return thetas
```

Error Msg 1: '-'
*Class 'tuple' does not define '**sub**', so the '-' operator cannot be used on its instances*
Error Msg 2: 'widths'
*Expected type 'tuple', got 'float' instead*
Maybe there are other possibilities of type-hinting that would work...
Thx