# PyCharm type hinting doesn't work with overloaded operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-overloading, pycharm

This was sort of touched on in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231541/pycharm-type-error-message/31367247#31367247), but never resolved.

I have a vector class:

```
class Vector2D(object):

    # ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    # ...

    def __truediv__(self, scalar):
        return Vector2D(self.x / scalar, self.y / scalar)
```

Then, I have a function that is type hinted to accept a Vector2D:

```
def foo(vector):
    """
    :type vector: Vector2D
    """
    print("<{}, {}>".format(vector.x, vector.y))
```

If I try to call `foo` like so, I get a strange warning saying `"Expected type 'Vector2D', got 'int' instead"`:

```
foo((Vector2D(1, 2) + Vector2D(2, 3)) / 2)
```

However, it works fine when I run it, and there is no warning when I explicitly use the methods of `Vector2d`:

```
foo(Vector2D(1, 2).__add__(Vector2D(2, 3)).__truediv__(2))
```

Please note I am using Python 2.7 but I have `from __future__ import division, print_function` at the top of all my modules.  Any help or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't add a comment, because my reputation is too low, but I can create an answer. Seems legit.

I tried you Code example (using operators) and I didn't get a warning.
Even when I left out `from __future__ import division, print_function`.
Also the right operands (or what are they called?) like `__rmul__` don't produce warnings. In fact the autocomplete works, too

```
(2 * Vector2D(0, 0))
```

I can press `.` and it shows me the attributes of the `Vector2D` class.

I have PyCharm 4.5.4 Professional.

You can however try to manually specify the return type in the operators:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    """
    :rtype: Vector2D
    """
    return ...
```

You can also try to clear the PyCharm-Cache: `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 4.5.4 Community Edition, so that may have something to do with it.  I tried your other solutions, but they didn't work for me.  I guess that's just another reason to upgrade :D.